# com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, aem

We are unsing Adobe CQ5 and have a memory problem.

A dump analysis with Eclipse Memory Analzyer showed that we have

```
104 instances of "com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 6,210,086,632 (80.61%) bytes.
```

Now 104 instances are not much, but 6GB are.

Each class has a `sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster raster` of 84 MB.

How can I find out which class references these renderers? If I click on "Path To CG Roots" I get nothing. At first I thought that the memory could be used by some static fields but the big structures (i.e., `raster`) are not static.

Comment: If there's indeed a problem in CQ about this, stackoverflow users might not be able to help. I would ask Adobe tech support if there's a known issue.

Comment: @BertrandDelacretaz We will, but up to know I had much more success asking on SO than opening a support ticket. The SO CQ5 community was much more helpful. I just have the hope that someone found a workaround for the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into this issue myself. It turns out to be a known issue with the Graphics Support Library. Open an Adobe ticket and request cq-5.5.0-hotfix-NPR-3368-1.2.zip, which basically includes the day-commons-gfx-2.1.28.jar. This appears to also work with 5.4, in case that's what you're using. Good luck!

Comment: We got the patch from Adobe and it's solving the problem. Many thanks again.

Comment: FWIW, that hotfix is now listed at http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/cq561-available-hotfixes.html